# fullcalendar after set state calendar goes automatically to todays date

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I dont understand the problem that I have.

if I hover on an event I set a state. Maybe today is 08-29. and I scroll to 10-30 because there is an event. if I hover this event I set a state automatically then the calendar scrolls to todays date 08-29 although I dont use gotoDate or any scroll functions. Whats the problem here ?

```
      <FullCalendar
        ref={ref}
        scrollTime={milliseconds - 86400000}
        resources={resource}
        // @ts-ignore
        events={query}
        schedulerLicenseKey="xxxx" 
        plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin, dayGrid, scrollGrid ]}
        initialView='resourceTimelineYear'
        allDayContent={(el) => console.log(el)}
        views={{
          resourceTimelineYear: {
            duration: '2 Years',
            slotDuration: { hours: 24 },
            visibleRange: {
              start: '2023-01-01',
              end: '2024-01-01'
            }
          },
          
        }}
        locale='de'
        selectOverlap
        stickyHeaderDates
        droppable
        height='auto'
        stickyFooterScrollbar
        aspectRatio={0.8}
        editable={false}
        select={handleSelectDate}
        eventDragStop={(e) => console.log('s')}
        eventClick={(e) => navigate(`/process/${e.event._def.extendedProps.booking_id}`)}
        eventMouseEnter={(e) => {
          setShow(true);
          }
        }
        resourceLabelDidMount={(el) => el.el.addEventListener('click', () => navigate(`/cars/${el.resource._resource.id}`))}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        //eventChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
        
        resourceGroupField='building'
      />
```

here is an video

https://streamable.com/rzggs2

€:

if I remove this:

```
        visibleRange: {
              start: '2023-01-01',
              end: '2024-01-01'
            }
```

then it works and dont scroll automatically back but then I dont have visible 2 year I see only one day then, I also can pay for fix